# Confused about SVG styling with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

The most d3.js examples use SVG to draw the diagrams, etc. This means for instance `rect` instead of `div`. This then again means, that CSS properties like `drop-shadow` cannot be applied.

The alternative approach is to define filters in `<defs>`. The same is true if you want to fill the `rect` with a gradient color. Is that right so far?

So I define some filter and gradients, but it seems very redundant to redefine these definitions for every page again. Wouldn't it be possible to reference all these definitions from a separate svg-file?

I tried things like: `filter: url(.../my_file.svg)` but it does not seem to work, but isn't that how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a file called `filters.svg`, and it contains a few filter defitions. It looks something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <filter id="my_filter" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    ...
  </filter>
</svg>
```

If you were using `my_filter` in that same document, you'd just refer to it using `#my_filter`. But you're not. You want to use it in another document. What you have to do then is refer to it in those documents as `/filters.svg#my_filter`. Like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="url(/filters.svg#my_filter)" />
</svg>
```

This is of course assuming that both documents are accessible from the same domain, and that they're located in the right places, etc. I don't know if this will work in CSS stylesheets, but it will work across SVG documents. Check out the [section on Linking in the SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Works in Firefox, but not Chrome yet :)